# XSD, create schema with unordered elements that also contains list

Tags: xml, xsd

I have that kind of XML:

```
<HEAD>
    <BUYER>1111</BUYER>
    <RECIPIENT>2222</RECIPIENT>
    <ADDRESS>33333</ADDRESS>
    <POSITION>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Name 1</NAME>
    </POSITION>
    <POSITION>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Name 2</NAME>
    </POSITION>
    <POSITION>
        <NUMBER>3</NUMBER>
        <NAME>Name 3</NAME>
    </POSITION>
</HEAD>
```

`BUYER`, `RECIPIENT`, `ADDRESS` tags can be placed in any order, but **before position tags**. Tags inside `POSITION` can be in any order.

I was trying to use `all` tag to describe like this:

```
<xs:element name="HEAD">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="BUYER">
            <xs:element name="RECIPIENT">
            <xs:element name="ADDRESS">
            <xs:element name="POSITION" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:all>
                         <xs:element name="NUMBER">
                         <xs:element name="NAME">
                     </xs:all>
                <xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
       </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Howerver, I found out that `unbounded` could not be used in `all`.

Is it possible to somehow make schema, that has unordered tags with array?

Comment: XSD 1.1 allows the `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, I think. But I don't see how a simple `xs:all` specifies your requirement to have the `BUYER`, `RECIPIENT` and `ADDRESS` before any `POSITION`.

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.0 the only way to achieve this is to enumerate all permitted orderings of BUYER, RECIPIENT, and ADDRESS.

In XSD 1.1 you could use xs:all to allow the elements to appear in any order, and then use an assertion to constrain it: `test="every $P in POSITION satisfies empty($P/following-sibling::*[not(self::POSITION)])`.